# Proxying sbt ivy repositories with artifactory

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory

I'm trying to do almost exactly what is described in the official sbt documentation, at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Proxy-Repositories.html. I'd like to proxy both maven and ivy packages, and it seems like only Artifactory supports both. I went through the installation and got things roughly working, except that I couldn't point my remote repository (for local caching) at e.g., sbt-plugin-releases because it uses a custom repository layout (including the sbt version), which isn't allowed in the free version of Artifactory.

How do other people do this? It can't be uncommon if there's a whole documentation page on it. Does doing sbt stuff with a proxied ivy repository have to cost me $2750 a year? It's a little frustrating because I don't need most of the Artifactory Pro features, but I don't think I can get by without the custom layouts. Nexus and Archiva only seem to support Maven.

Answer (score 1):

In Artifactory custom layouts (actually, any layouts) aren't enforcing. That means they have no impact on proxying, resolving, deploying or any other basic operation of your repository manager. As described [in the documentation](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts), layouts offer the following facilities:

- Automatic snapshot/integration versions cleanup
- Deleting old versions Conversions between remote and local layouts
- Conversions between 2 local layouts when moving or copying
- Resolution conversions from a virtual repository to its underlying
  repositories (where the virtual repository has its own layout
  defined)

Also please note that Artifactory OSS version comes with with all the popular layouts for JVM dependency managers, such as:

- Maven 2/3
- Ivy (default layout)
- Gradle (Wharf cache default layout)
- Maven 1

So, the problem is elsewhere. If you could ellaborate why you "couldn't point my remote repository (for local caching) at e.g., sbt-plugin-releases", inc. the error you get, we gladly helped you.

Comment: Oh, perhaps it would work then. I just saw that the instructions on there said that the layout had to be exactly as specified, saw that I couldn't change it on artifactory, and assumed something would break later on. What does the layout preference do, then?

Comment: Yeah, my confusion was around your "(default layout)" point, since the blog post explicitly says "Note that the ivy resolver pattern is important, make sure that yours matches the one shown or you may not be able to resolve sbt plugins." and provides a non-default layout to use with it. I'll try it out tomorrow, but anyway, that was the source of my concern. Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding the repo that @copumpkin is talking about to our Artifactory instance as a remote repository, and it *does not* work. The remote repo saves properly, but it will never actually perform any proxying. The remote repo in Artifactory always appears as empty, and will respond with a 404 when asked for any specific artifacts.

Comment: @monitorjbl Which URL you are adding?

Comment: It's the repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/ one. It redirects to https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, but neither of them work when set up for a remote repo.

Comment: https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases should work. It works for me, I just checked.